# Views 3 vertical reading list

Tags: 7, views

When displaying a view of all the terms on my site in asc order, they read from A-z down.  Apply a grid-2 to each row, and they read as so:

```
A B C D E F G
H I J K L M N
O P Q R S T U
```

This is difficult reading in my opinion.  I would like them to read as so:

```
A D G J M
B E H K N
C F I L O
```

Is it possible to achieve a vertical list like this?

Answer (score 2):

Could you try changing the ordering for the grid to be vertical and not horizontal. I am assuming that the you are using a grid as the format for displaying your data in the view.

Comment: No, I am using unformatted list.  This is just a block of links, and not data, so using a table grid is not the right way to go.

Comment: From your question I understood you are getting terms. it is possible to get the term names and use grid format for the view together with a block display.

Comment: I can get it to work just fine with grid display, but...tables are only for data, and are not responsive friendly.